# google map shows up in FF fine but not IE

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps

I am at a lost why it is not showing up

It is google map and followed this tutorial.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax.html

problem is the map shows up in IE but there are no markers ? Anyone have any ideas

Here is the page Took out page since it is working now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Barefoot Runners User Map</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=key" 
       type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var iconBlue = new GIcon(); 
    iconBlue.image = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png';
    iconBlue.shadow = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png';
    iconBlue.iconSize = new GSize(12, 20);
    iconBlue.shadowSize = new GSize(22, 20);
    iconBlue.iconAnchor = new GPoint(6, 20);
    iconBlue.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(5, 1);

    var iconRed = new GIcon(); 
    iconRed.image = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png';
    iconRed.shadow = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png';
    iconRed.iconSize = new GSize(12, 20);
    iconRed.shadowSize = new GSize(22, 20);
    iconRed.iconAnchor = new GPoint(6, 20);
    iconRed.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(5, 1);

    var customIcons = [];
    customIcons["restaurant"] = iconBlue;
    customIcons["bar"] = iconRed;

    function load() {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
        //map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(38.323272, -95.712891), 4);

        // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
        GDownloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml3.php", function(data) {
          var xml = GXml.parse(data);
          var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
            var address = markers[i].getAttribute("street");

            var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("latitude")),
                                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("longitude")));
            var marker = createMarker(point, name, address);
            map.addOverlay(marker);
          }
        });
      }
    }

    function createMarker(point, name, address, type) {
      var marker = new GMarker(point, customIcons[type]);
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
      });
      return marker;
    }
    //]]>
  </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="load()" onunload="GUnload()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 600px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors? Warnings? Does the HTML validate? Is it being served as HTML or XHTML? Etc, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it fails on the `var xml = GXml.parse(data)` so obviously there's something wrong with the xml returned by `phpsqlajax_genxml3.php`

```
<marker name="Olle Albinsson" street="Professorsvägen" latitude="65.617922" longitude="22.152571" />
```

seems like special chars?

**UPDATE**

To debug these bugs in Internet Explorer you can use the "Developer Tools". When you press F12 within IE you get some firebug/chrome debug like tool. Checking the console will give you alote of information when have javascript errors.

In your case i checked the `Network` tab and copy paste the content of the xml into a document. The IE developer tool console said there we're problems on line *** what seems to be the marker as specified above.

Good luck

Comment: any ideas on how to troubleshoot this issue ? I am just pulling data from a database.

Comment: see my updated post with the marker that's causing the problem.. maybe you could use the php `htmlspecialchar()` function or another encoding function

Comment: Thank you I will look into that. How did you find the one having the issue  I was looking all over for it. I am new to this and would love to know any tools or how you found which character or line it was .

Comment: Okay i think i took care of that special character but it messed up again. Can you please check if it is not stopping at olle albinsson. I will wait to see how you found where to look as now I am still unable to figure out which one to look at to fix.

Comment: yes thank you with your help i got it working last night. Now time to post a new question with silly drupal. I found it easier to go to the phpsqlajax_genxml3.php in firefox it would point to the character that is wrong with a mark. Then i would look in myphpadmin and find what it was suppose to be and add it to special characters.